# How to kill all tmux sessions (or at least multiple sessions) from the CLI?

Tags: process, tmux

How to kill all tmux sessions (or at least multiple sessions) from the (Ubuntu) CLI?

When I do `ps aux | grep tmux` I see 3 processes:

```
UU      2970  0.0  0.0  19556  1228 pts/0    S+   02:48   0:00 tmux
UU      3445  0.0  0.0  12944   988 pts/5    S+   03:31   0:00 grep --color=auto tmux
UU     27557  0.0  0.2  29788  4840 ?        Ss   Jan04   0:02 tmux
```

How could I kill all of these at once (or at least some of them, selectivity) ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can kill all of these processes with the command:

```
pkill -f tmux
```

It kills all processes (full list) of the matching name (tmux).

---

Note for newcomers: This way could serve you to kill all process of other matching names.

Comment: what about by username?

Answer (score 328):

You can use `tmux kill-server` to *cleanly and gracefully* kill all tmux open sessions (and server).

If you are inside a tmux session you would like to keep, use `tmux kill-session -a` to close all other sessions.

To close a specific session, use `tmux list-sessions` to identify the session you want to kill, and then use `tmux kill-session -t targetSession` to kill that specific session.

Also you can *grossly* kill all tmux processes with `pkill -f tmux`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `ps aux | grep tmux` after `tmux kill-server` still shows a tmux process... Same goes with `pkill -f tmux` as in my answer. Can you explain this? Thanks,

Comment: @Benia are you sure you are not just seeing the `grep tmux` process (which is included in the ps output of your original question)?

Comment: Not sure I understand.

Comment: If you issue `ps aux | grep blablablawhichdoesntexist` it will always show at least one line, corresponding to the `grep blablablawhichdoesntexist` command.

Comment: Are you missing `-t` flag, cos it shows error without `-t` flag set for killing a particular session. `Usage: kill-session [-a] [-t target-session]`

Comment: It used to be very painful `tmux ls | grep : | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print substr($1, 0, length($1)-1)}' | xargs kill`

Comment: How can one kill a range of sessions? For instance, suppose I want to end sessions 3 through 6 but leave 0 through 2 and 7 through 9 unaffected.

Comment: What does "gracefully" mean? I'm just asking because I see that word being used frequently but never really know what that means.

Comment: @Sean It usually refers to something that shows grace and/or elegance. In this context gracefully means in the best and most appropriate way possible, using the most appropriate interface and avoiding crudely killing processes.

Comment: what about by username?

Answer (score 27):

This would list and kill all the sessions:

```bsh
tmux list-sessions | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}' | \
     ifne xargs -n 1 tmux kill-session -t
```

Comment: to others who might run into this (like me) -  if you're on a tmux session running this, you might want to kill all the other sessions first before killing your own :P

Comment: @HoMan You might be interested [on my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378750/349837)

Comment: what about by username?

Answer (score 7):

Given:

```
# tmux ls
session-0a: 1 windows (created Sat Dec  5 02:31:35 2020) [117x30]
session-84: 1 windows (created Sat Dec  5 01:55:18 2020) [190x47] (attached)
session-b3: 1 windows (created Sat Dec  5 03:23:44 2020) [94x13]
session-b2: 1 windows (created Sat Dec  5 02:45:00 2020) [104x14]
session-ae: 1 windows (created Sat Dec  5 01:55:18 2020) [190x47] (attached)
```

This will kill all sessions not attached by someone:

```
tmux list-sessions | grep -v attached | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 tmux kill-session -t || echo No sessions to kill
```

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411616/grep-regex-not-containing-string
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt
3. [How to kill all tmux sessions (or at least multiple sessions) from the CLI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868186/how-to-kill-all-tmux-sessions-or-at-least-multiple-sessions-from-the-cli)

Answer (score 2):

Here another solution that allows you to select easily between useful sessions and the ones to delete, enter in `tmux`:

Check your sessions pressing:

```
ctrl+b+s
```

Then move with the arrows and press `t` to target as many sessions as you want to kill.

Press `:` and write

```
kill-session
```

I think this solution is the faster one as you don't need to write the name or number of the sessions to delete, but you rather use the UI of the own tmux to delete all selected at the same time.

In the same menu, you can also delete them one by one pressing `x` to delete and `y` to accept the deletion, so you write even less if you don't have many sessions to delete.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small app in C which does this.

It's called kkill, you can simply

```
kkill tmux tmux-server tmux-something etc
```

this will kill all tmux processes running. it is a lot simpler than pkill.

https://github.com/giorgossaridakis/kkill

21 December 2021 - updated kkill.c, added a tsr kkiller.c who 'll watch for processes and send them SIGKILL as they become active

Comment: In the spirit of GNU, Linux and FOSS, why don't you just link to a Github (or similar) page with the source code of your app, so people can check it out for themselves?

Comment: you are right. https://github.com/giorgossaridakis/kkill

Comment: I also amended the answer

Comment: @ArturMeinild maybe you'll also need kkiller.c

Answer (score 0):

Kill all sessions with no one attached ([based on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014428/349837)):

```
tmux ls | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}!/attached/{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 tmux kill-ses -t
```